# how to skip a line inside stream reader?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, streamreader

using streamreader, if line starts with '0' skip the line???

```
string FileToProcess = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"up.FolderPath");
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FileToProcess))
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = sr.ReadLine();
        if (line.StartsWith("0"))
        {
            line.Skip();
            // ????have to put a number line in here
            // But i just want to skip the line it is on
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just negate the if? `if(!line.StartsWith("0")) { // Do stuff with lines you do care about }`

Comment: because i have other conditions and would like to kow how to skip the current line please

Comment: why is -points? please clarify?

Comment: Read about `if-else` condition

Comment: If you can be helpful, please do...else...click next?

Comment: I downvoted it. I found your question difficult to understand. Especially the part that says `????have to put a number line in here`, the code is poorly formatted and also I'm all for short, succinct questions, but there is hardly no scope or background to your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can skip a line by just not doing anything with it. Quickest way, use `continue;`...

```
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    string line = sr.ReadLine();
    if (line.StartsWith("0"))
    {
        continue;
    }
    //process line logic
}
```

Using `continue` will effectively jump to the start of the `while` loop again, which will then proceed to reading the next line,

This is based on my understanding that you want to skip lines that start with `"0"`

Answer (score 1):

```
string FileToProcess = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"up.FolderPath");
      using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FileToProcess))
      {
          while (!sr.EndOfStream)
          {
                string line = sr.ReadLine();
                if (line.StartsWith("0"))
                {
                      continue;
                }
                else{
                      //Do stuff here
                }
          }
     }
```

Answer (score -3):

Do something with the line only when it do not start with '0'

Comment: Wat?! How can you check if it starts with `"0"` before you read it?

Comment: @musefan: The code I posted is not at all tested.. it is just an idea

Comment: It should be blatantly obvious that this code would not work. `line` hasn't been assigned to anything

Comment: you should have tested it first, as it is wrong. After your edit, your answer is now very poor. It should be a comment at best, though I personally wouldn't even bother with a comment. Sorry, but it just isn't useful